# Square root calculation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

want to calculate square root of given input so i used this code

```
var no1:Number = 2;
var no2:Number; //input for calculation
var total:Number;
total=Math.pow(no2,(1/no1));
```

its working , but i faced problem such as:-
if i give

> no2 = 25;

then it shows

> total=4.9999999

to overcome this problem i used below code

> total=Math.ceil(Math.pow(no2,(1/no1)));

but its okey for 25 .

> total = 5

problem was if i give 21,22,23,24

for all this input it shows 5

so is there any other solutions ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take the nth root. You can feed the output of your function into arbitrary rounding function like this:

```
/**
 * Rounds input number to specified number of decimal places. For example
 * round(4.568, 2) will return 4.57, and round(4.99, 2) will return 5.
 */
function round(num:Number, toDecimalPlaces:uint) {
   var factor:uint = Math.pow(10, toDecimalPlaces);
   return Math.round(num * factor) / factor;
}

/**
 * Returns nth root to two decimal places.
 */
function nthRoot(n:uint, num:Number) {
   return round(Math.pow(num, (1 / n)), 2);
}
```

Comment: for √25 ....rounded-result = 8.881784197001252e-16....so how can i convert it to 0.000000000000001 @Peter

Comment: I would actually suggest using the second solution instead of the first. :)

Answer (score 1):

[There's a function for that](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#sqrt%28%29).

```
var total:Number = Math.sqrt(no2);
```

Comment: ya i know that but i give no1 as variable because i want to calculate 3√(no2), 4√(no2),5√(no2).....

Comment: 3√(no2) is just a double sqrt so `Math.sqrt(Math.sqrt(no2))`, 4√(no2)  is a triple sqrt etc. So just make a function that iteratively square roots the number and returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

my actual code was like this

```
var str:String=view.numDisplay.text;//input string
var power:Number = Number(inString.charAt(inString.indexOf('√') - 1));//to get the value before √ i.e no1
var no1:Number;
var no2:Number;
var total:Number;
if(power)
   no1=v;
else
   no1=2;
no2=getSubTerm();//method to find no2 it returns the number for calculation
total=Math.ceil(Math.pow(no2,(1/no1)));
```